# IE9 does not accept unicode string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, internet-explorer-9, clojurescript, unicode-string

I tried to run my webapp with IE 9 (it already runs well in Firefox and Chrome) and  I continuously get The error

> Script1014: Invalid Character

The debugger yields one line of code that contains the string "\ufdd0'keywordize-keys". I realize that this is an artifact of ClojureScript which I use to compile down to Javascript. I.e. Clojurscript symbol `:keywordize-keys`.

Now I was looking for a solution and I tried adding the encoding to the import HTML tag

`<script src="js/advanced.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

this, however, does not make the error go away. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the webserver serves the `js/advanced.js` resource with the correct charset.

See http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php